# React Native with Expo: is firebase-admin necessary?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo, firebase-admin

I need to fetch my firebase db before the authentication process.
My firebase rules are restricted to authenticated users for both read and write.

So I've installed firebase-admin.

in the App.js

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
```

and after initialised it

```
 const serviceAccount = require("./pathtocredentials.json");
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://myappdbname.firebaseio.com"
  });
```

This is the error that I have:

> The package at "node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\firebase-namespace.js"
>   attempted to import the Node standard library module "fs". It failed
>   because React Native does not include the Node standard library. Read
>   more at
>   https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/faq/#can-i-use-nodejs-packages-with-expo
>   Failed building JavaScript bundle.

So I searched and ..."Since your app is running inside JS VM on either iPhone or Android, the only way to access filesystem is to use react-native-fs"

What I want is just to check in my db if a user exists before let it authenticate. Did I necesserily need firebase-admin and react-native-fs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

firebase-admin is not meant for web frontend code. It's for backend code running nodejs.  You won't be able to effectively use firebase-admin in a React or any browser environment.  On top of that, it's not really necessary if you just want to query your database from your frontend.

All you really need to do is [read data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) using the normal Firebase JavaScript API for web.  You can tell if a node exists in the database by checking if its DataSnapshot object actually [exists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#exists).